# how to make poetry-script outputs available when running in ipython?

Tags: python, python-poetry

After running `!my_super_script` in ipython or jupiter notebook, I would like to have access to `a` and `b` script output inside the interpreter (which is not currently the case: `$a` *"NameError: name 'a' is not defined"*)

In other world I would like to archive the same behavior as running the following command in ipython `%run ~/my-package/src/my_package/cli.py`

### My setup:

`$poetry new --src my-package`

```
$ pwd
~/proj/my-package

$ tree
├── pyproject.toml
├── src
│   └── my_package
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── cli.py
└── tests
    └── __init__.py
```

```
# pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry.scripts]
my_super_script = 'my_package.cli:main'
```

```
# cli.py

def main():
    a = 1
    b = [1, 2]
    return a, b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b = main()
```